# how to know which parameters are supported by an api when sending a get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I was busy with a tutorial based on the Ionic and Angularjs Frameworks(mentioned just for the sake of context).In one of the tutorials a get request with parameters is made to a REST API.

What I wanted to know is how do I figure out which parameters are supported by the api and what names to give to the parameters, because when I tried playing with the parameter names that were assigned initially by the tutor(who didn't explain the concept of the parameters), a different set of results were returned, which obviously meant that the parameters were being ignored,because of the change of name in the parameters.

To make it even more confusing(for myself atleast) the parameter names did not even match the names of the properties which were present in the result object,according to 'developer tools' in both chrome and firefox. Here's a [link](https://codecraftpro.com/api/samples/v1/coffee/) to the api that I'm making  use of,  if you want to test it you'll have to get an api token at [codecraftpro](http://www.codecraftpro.com).Unfortunately, you'd have to subscribe to their newsletter to get an api token, but, you've been warned!

Your assistance would be highlt appreciated, thanks in advance!

Here's a code snippet to provide more clarity with regards to my question:

```js
var params = {
              page:  1,
              lat:  51.5074,
              lon:   0.1278,
            };
            $http.get('https://codecraftpro.com/api/samples/v1/coffee/', {params: params})
```

Comment: At least for me, I usually read the documentation. As far as I know, it's up to the creator of the API for making it clear how it's used.

Comment: I looked for documentation regarding the api but couldn't find anything.